# Flutter Scrollbar not draggable when thumbsVisibility true

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, drag

My Scrollbar code

```
Scrollbar(
          thumbVisibility: true,
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 1000,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text("Hitesh"),
                );
              }),
        ),
```

If thumbsVisibility property is true then dragging by mouse not working on web.
If I make thumbsVisibility property false then dragging work properly.

This issue occured after updating flutter.

Whats the Solution?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `controller` for both `ScrollBar` and `ListView`.

```
Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      controller: controller,
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 1000,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text("Hitesh"),
            );
          }),
    );
```

And in the class property

```
final controller = ScrollController();
```